# Show that $(A\cup B)\times C=(A\times C)\cup (B\times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is my try attempt:

> 22) ${\text{Show that }(A\cup B)\times C=(A\times C)\cup (B\times C)]\\
> \text{We take some }{(x,y)\in[(A\times C)\cup(B\times C)]\\
> = [x\in A\wedge y\in C]\vee[x\in B\wedge y\in C]\\
> = [x\in A\vee x\in B]\wedge[y\in C]\\
> = [x\in (A\cup B)]\wedge[y\in C]\\
> = (x,y)\in (A\cup B)\times C
> }}$

Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: `\cup \times \in` gives $\cup\ \times\ \in\quad$ I think it is not too difficult to type this directly in Latex, the rest is just plain text.

Comment: The pair structure is lost a bit in this proof, in first $=$ line $[\cdots]$ represents a pair, and the next line the same bracket is now singletons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've shown that $(A\times C)\cup(B\times C)\subseteq (A\cup B)\times C$. You need to prove the other direction as well, for equality.

Comment: Thaks! I think if I do the same but going backward it should work, right?

Comment: That's right, the steps are the same, but reversed.

Comment: If you indicate your steps as equivalences instead of implications, then you take care of both directions at once.